# How do I get value from tags?

Tags: php, regex, dom

I have this code:

```
<dl class="ui-attr-list util-clearfix">
<dt data-attr="">size:</dt>
<dd title="3-6-9-12M">3-6-9-12M</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="ui-attr-list util-clearfix">
<dt  data-attr="">color:</dt>
<dd title="as the pictures show">as the pictures show</dd>
</dl>
```

And I need to get the following values from the tags:

- `size`
- `3-6-9-12M`
- `color:`

Can someone help me?

Comment: if you have tried something, then please show us the code, SO is not a free coding service

Comment: Step 1: don't use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to pull those values out of the HTML. If that's the case, you could look at something called SimpleHTMLDom. It's a PHP library which allows you to load HTML into it, and be able to search/access elements in the html.

Comment: Can you please link in the library to your answer